# Accessing a IBOutlet NSTextView from a background thread?

Tags: xcode, multithreading, macos, swift, nstextview

So I spent hours trying to debug my code, turns out I was trying to access my NSTextView from a background thread. Long story short, I tried using dispatch_async in my code, still throws a nil when unwrapping. If I change it to ? it won't crash but it won't output anything. I'm writing my application using XCode 6 and Swift OSX. Everything is delegated properly, and dragged properly. I have two classes, one viewcontroller, and one class called Server. Server initializes a viewcontroller method, and calls view.output() because I'm trying to make a "live" console log. It's showing that my server object is nil, and consoleOutput is nil but the variable recv is not nil.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextViewDelegate {
var server: Server!

func output(recv: String?) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.consoleOutput.string! += recv!
        }
    }
}
```

}

It's a threading error, I need to edit the NSTextView from the main thread. It's throwing this error,

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
Printing description of self: 
(VegasPanel.ViewController) self = 0x00006000000e2c00 {      
AppKit.NSViewController = { 
AppKit.NSResponder = { 
ObjectiveC.NSObject = {} 
} 
} 
server = nil 
consoleOutput = nil }
```

Output is being called from my Server class, like this,

```
class Server: NSObject, GCDAsyncSocketDelegate {
   let received:String?
   var view = ViewController()

    func socket(sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didReadData data:NSData, withTag tag:Int)
    {
        view.output(received)
    }
 }
```

Comment: If `recv` is `nil` then `recv!` will crash (since its nil) and `recv?` will silently not execute the statement. So that works as designed.

Comment: @ThomasKilian recv is not nil, that's the wierd part. It is consoleOutput that is crashing because self -> server = nil, consoleOutput = nil. That's what it reads when it crashes. I have a feeling it has to do with me initializing ViewController() causing my server() to become nil.

Comment: You're also unwrapping `consoleOutput.string`. If that is nil it will also crash. Did you initialize it with an empty string?

Comment: @ThomasKilian no I did not, I don't think I can. I think it's a threading issue.

Comment: Why can't you? It's a property. Just initialize it like `var consoleOutput = ""`

Comment: @ThomasKilian I did that, it didn't fix the issue. Still getting a nil. It's trying to modify the NSTextView from the background thread, I need it to modify from the main thread. I am getting, fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
Printing description of self:
(VegasPanel.ViewController) self = 0x00006000000e2c00 {
  AppKit.NSViewController = {
    AppKit.NSResponder = {
      ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}
    }
  }
  server = nil
  consoleOutput = nil
}

Comment: Can you put that in your question. Hard to read as comment. From where is `output` called?